# how to start console with custom size without flicker?

Tags: c++, windows, console, mingw

I know this method of setting console size :

```
system("mode 128,128");
```

But when program starts, system at first is trying to create console with standard size and when execution reaches mode command - only then the console window gets my desired size. The question is how to make console according to my needs right from the start.

I'm speaking here of running the program with double click from explorer, so the console belongs to the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more luck linking your program as a GUI application rather than command-line, calling `AllocConsole()` to create a console, and then `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` to resize it. The console would still get created before the resizing, but because you are using the API calls directly, the delay may be small enough to not be noticeable.

If you do this, you may need to do some setup to connect the C and C++ standard input/output/error to the console you created. For that, take a look at `_fdopen()` and `ios_base::sync_with_stdio()`.